# Reformat SD Card from internal to portable

Tags: sd-card, storage, adoptable-storage, formatting

Device: Redmi Note 11

I formatted a SanDisk SD card as internal, using the Android's native file app (com.google.android.documentsui) but now I can't see the card anywhere.

However when inserted, the phone storage info shows available space of the SD Card.

How do I make this SD card as portable again?

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious but the solution to this problem is — delete all the partitions of the SD card and then format it to FAT or exFAT (preferably). For this you would most certainly require a PC/Laptop.

Formatting without deleting the partitions won't help.